# Remotely access HBase Table List using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;

public class ListTables {

    public static void main(String args[])throws MasterNotRunningException, IOException {
        ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        System.out.println("stage 1. . . . ");
        Configuration conf =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.*.***");
        conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.*.***:60000");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
        conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure");
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

        try {
            HBaseAdmin admin1 = (HBaseAdmin)connection.getAdmin();
            System.out.println("stage 3. . . . ");
            HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor[] = admin1.listTables();
            for (int i=0; i<tableDescriptor.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(tableDescriptor[i].getNameAsString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
stage 1. . . . 
stage 3. . . .
```

**This is the Error**

After this line, i'm waiting for huge time, but No RESPONSE.

Comment: Did  you try to get table list with the help of HBase shell? Does it work?

Comment: Yup, Its working in hbase shell > list.

Comment: Are you sure you need the config option  conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure")? if not, try to remove that. I tried this code by myself and in my case it works perfectly without that option and gets no response with it.

Comment: Yes @max i tried the both way with theproperty- "/hbase-unsecure" and also with  "/hbase" but not working for me .

Comment: Actually this line is not executing, i thing some super user privilege is needed to execute this line "admin1.listTables();" from this line, NO RESPONSE!

Comment: First check your connection. I doubt if its establishing connection with HBase or not. Use below code to check connection.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I had to create the log4j.properties, It is because Hadoop use log4j to write its logs:

project Java: resources / log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\path of your `enter code here`file\\pruebas\\log\\log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I  hope this helps you.